# Why hexagons? The maximal minimum of a sum of cosines on the plane with frequencies on the unit circle

Tags: inequalities, nonlinear-optimization, trigonometric-sums

We wish to maximize the minimum of a weighted sum of cosines in the plane, when the frequency components are on the unit circle. Formally:
$$\max_{\{ a_i,\theta_i,\phi_i  \}_{i=1}^{N} } \min_{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2} \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \cos(\cos(\theta_k)x+ \sin(\theta_k)y + \phi_k) $$
$$ \mathrm{such} \,\,\, \mathrm{that}: \forall i: \theta_i\in[0,\pi),\phi_i\in[0,\pi), a_i\in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k^2=1,  \forall j\neq i: \theta_i \neq \theta_j $$

Prove (or disprove): for any $N\geq3$ a maximizer of this objective is the symmetric hexagonal solution

$$ \theta_1=0,\theta_2=\pi/3,\theta_3=2\pi/3 ,$$

with  $\forall i=1,2,3: a_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ and $\phi_i=0$, and $\forall i>3: a_i=0$.

Background: I believe this problem is strongly connected to my previous question
[Maximal minimum for a sum of two (or more) cosines](https://mathoverflow.net/q/209071/44790) .

Thanks in advance!